# Sending json POST request in Swift returns error in reading the json

Tags: json, swift, http, post, request

I'm trying to send a post request from a Swift (5.1) client, using to following json as request body:

```
let json: [String: Any] = ["userName": "reef123",
                               "password": "abcd1234",
                               "wins": 100]

    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted)
    let valid = JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(json);
    print(valid)
    // Set HTTP Request Body
    request.httpBody = jsonData


    // Perform HTTP Request
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            // Check for Error
            if let error = error {
                print("Error took place \(error)")
                return
            }

            let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
                    print(responseJSON)
                }
    }
    task.resume()
```

where "userName" is a required field.
I get the following error:

```
["message": User validation failed: userName: Path `userName` is required., "errors": {
    userName =     {
        kind = required;
        message = "Path `userName` is required.";
        name = ValidatorError;
        path = userName;
        properties =         {
            message = "Path `userName` is required.";
            path = userName;
            type = required;
        };
    };
}, "_message": User validation failed, "name": ValidationError]
```

sending the same json from postman does give the expected result from server

Comment: Why are you still using `JSONSerialization`? Can't you use `Codable`?

Comment: Show the postman request and response screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
First of all the reason - the node js server did not accept any of the request body. While in postman there was no need to change any default setting, seems that in swift adding the following code describing headers is needed.

```
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

When the header values are as above the node js server is accepting the request body correctly.